# Can not install java jdk 8

Tags: java, 15.04, openjdk, jdk

I've installed ubunut 15.04 recently and I've tried to install java JDK 8 but I can not, and I don't know why.

I have fallow all that commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

And after that I checked my java version and I've got a error:

```
root@vlad-X550JX:/usr# java --version
Unrecognized option: --version
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Please help me anyone, how I can make it work?

Comment: What does `java -version` (with just a **single** hyphen) say?

Comment: I am agreeing with @steeldriver.  The version check is done with a single hyphen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to see if Java is installed you need to check the version with a single hyphen.

`java -version`

The fact that this is throwing an error at all indicates that java is installed. :)